# Are Custom Labels Cached?

Tags: customsetting, customlabel, design-patterns

There was a requirement to store some key value pairs that will be frequently accessed and the current setup is that is being stored in custom labels. I was wondering if there is any evidence of Custom Label pairs being cached similar to custom settings. If not then I will be migrating to custom settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom labels are not cached. label values are pulled when it is referred.

You can use Custom metadata types if the values are not dependent on orgs and can be migrated through metadata deployment like changeset or Force.com UI.

You can use Custom settings if values are dependent on org and cached.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) question

[Custom Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_about.htm&type=5) is not thing, that you have to use in your case. From documentation it says:

> Custom labels enable developers to create multilingual applications by
>   automatically presenting information (for example, help text or error
>   messages) in a user’s native language. Custom labels are custom text
>   values that can be accessed from Apex classes, Visualforce pages, or
>   Lightning components. The values can be translated into any language
>   Salesforce supports.

Are you sure, that you want to translate some api key or password? :)

[Custom Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm), and even [Custom Metadata Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5) is better (you can deploy custom metadat records as normal metadata).

In case you will work with frequenly accessed data (such as acces token) use [Platfrom Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm).

Comment: I was considering platform Cache but it has its own share of [problems](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2017/01/salesforce-platform-cache-expect.html) :)